# How do I edit a jupyter notebook cell's tags in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am editing a .ipynb file in Visual Studio Code, with the file open in VS code's Jupyter Notebook editor.

When I edit this notebook in the Jupyter Notebook App (i.e. if I were not using VS code, instead using the interface described [here](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html#notebook-app)), I could add tags to cells by clicking View > Cell Toolbar > Tags, and then entering tags into the UI that comes up.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in VS Code?

I am aware I can reopen the file in a text editor view and edit the JSON directly. But I am looking for something a bit more user friendly than this.

Comment: Not possible at this time. There are two tickets requesting this feature, both are still pending. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1121 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1182

Answer (score 3):

Try installing this [jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) on vs code.

On my old windows 7 I used to use this. It has the same interface as when you open Jupiter in your browser but you don't need to load a bunch of stuff to open jupyter. You can open it in one single click like changing text file while writing code inside vc code.

Also you need to install one library to use it but unfortunately I can't remember the library as I don't use python or Jupiter anymore.

Comment: Thanks - the VS code Jupyter extension is the VS code Jupyter Notebook editor I am using already. If you're able to figure out what the library is, or how to edit the metadata using this extension, that would be helpful.

Sorry I didn't specify which VS code editor I was using in my question - it's the default extension so I had assumed people would assume that.

Comment: You can try opening it and it should prompt you to install some library (I used to get a prompt while trying to open a Jupiter for testing inside my virtual environment). Also you need the Python extension from Microsoft (I think you already have it). The 1st load can be slow depending on your pc.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have finally released an extra extension to support this.

- [ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags)

See this long running [github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter issue #1182](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1182) and [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1182#issuecomment-1254098790) recently closing the issue.

Be ware however, that while you can set tags, e.g. `raises-exception`, which is meant to make the runtime expect and ignore the exception and keep on running more cells, but the `vscode-jupyter` extension that runs the cells does not always honor tag features the same way that the standard Jupyter notebook runtime does, and so, disappointingly, it's still difficult to demo common mistakes or what not to do (exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/metadata.html) is a python code cell which enables to change all the cell tags.

```
import nbformat as nbf
from glob import glob

# Collect a list of all notebooks in the content folder
notebooks = glob("**/*.ipynb", recursive=True)
notebooks_windows = []
for i in notebooks:
    j = i.replace("\\", "/")
    notebooks_windows.append(j)
notebooks_windows

# Text to look for in adding tags
text_search_dict = {
    "# HIDDEN": "remove-cell",  # Remove the whole cell
    "# NO CODE": "remove-input",  # Remove only the input
    "# HIDE CODE": "hide-input"  # Hide the input w/ a button to show
}

# Search through each notebook and look for the text, add a tag if necessary
for ipath in notebooks_windows:
    ntbk = nbf.read(ipath, nbf.NO_CONVERT)

    for cell in ntbk.cells:
        cell_tags = cell.get('metadata', {}).get('tags', [])
        for key, val in text_search_dict.items():
            if key in cell['source']:
                if val not in cell_tags:
                    cell_tags.append(val)
        if len(cell_tags) > 0:
            cell['metadata']['tags'] = cell_tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy everything in .py file with the unremovable tags, paste that into a plaintext file. The tags are now just editable text. Remove them, Save As or copy/paste back to the .py file.